# Why matplotlib graphs and icons look different on two computers with the same OS?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two old computers both running Windows XP and here is how the same Matplotlib graph looks like on one and on another:

#01:

[image: PC with screen resolution 1280x1024]

#02:

[image: Laptop with screen resolution 1024x768]

The only difference is computer #01 is desktop PC with screen resolution 1280x1024 and the computer #02 is laptop with screen resolution 1024x768. In fact, the laptop is running SP3 and the desktop computer is running SP2 but the window on laptop looks worse although color depth on both computers is 32 bit. Furthermore, the laptop is running Python 2.7.13 and the desktop computer is running Python 2.7.11

Could it be the difference in graph styles and icons is because of the display resolution and/or the display drivers?

**EDIT:**
By adding `plt.style.use("classic")` into the #02 the graphs now look the same but the icons are still different.

Comment: any idea why the application icons are different? get a 3rd computer

Comment: @micah: Well, that I would like to know. I asked: 'Could it be the difference in graph styles `and icons` is because...'.

Comment: @micah: I solved the problem with the graphs but the icons remained different. I edited the question by adding what I did to make the graphs look the same.

Comment: I suspect you're using two different GUI backends on the machines. What is the output of `plt.get_backend()` on each?

Comment: @bnaecker: It is the same on both computers: `TkAgg`

Comment: Same versions of `matplotlib` itself?

Comment: @bnaecker: There was an older matplotlib version on the desktop computer, now they are the same and I had to put `plt.style.use("classic")` into the #01 as well but now I got these uglier icons. How do I set the colorful icons as were in the older vesion of matplotlib?

Comment: I have to ask. Why do you care that the application windows look different on the two machines?

Comment: @bnaecker: The main reason for this question was because the graph looked worse but I like the old colorful icons more than the new ones as well, so why not try to make them look better too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious reason for two different outputs from matplotlib is of course that you have two different versions of matplotlib installed. (Why would the computer change the matplotlib output?)

- The first image is produced with a matplotlib version **<= 1.5**
- The second image is produced with a matplotlib version **>= 2.0**

All differences between the versions are shown in [Changes to the default style](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html).

In matplotlib >= 2.0 you may use the `mpl.style.use('classic')` command to revert back to the old style. This will not change the icons on the toolbar since the old icons are not distributed with the newer versions. You may however copy them from the old version to the new one if that is desired.

Comment: `plt.style.use("classic")` worked well for the graph style but it seems they changed the icon format, there are `.png`, `.ppm` and `.gif` icons and the old ones couldn't be just copied over the new ones. I installed the old matplotlib in another virtual environment to compare old and new icon files.

Comment: BTW, I didn't think the computer would change the matplotlib's output, I thought matplotlib might change the output based on screen resolution or some other parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by "old ones couldn't be just copied over the new ones"? What prevented that?

Comment: For example, in matplotlib 1.5.3 there are `back.png`, `back.ppm`, `back.xpm`, `matplotlib.gif`, `matplotlib.ppm` etc. while in matplotlib 2.2.2 there are `back.gif`, `matplotlib.png`, `matplotlib.ppm`. In matplotlib 1.5.3 there are 45 icon files while in matplotlib 2.2.2 there are 36 icon files. I am not sure if I can just copy and paste the files from old (1.5.3) to the new (2.2.2) matplotlib folder because the result would be some unexpected combination of the old and the new icons.