# How could I get the desired matplotlib 3d plot style?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I copied a snippet from [here](https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/1db8d69b4b65e8bc66a6) and run it but didn't get the desired style.

**Code for reproduction**

```
#!/usr/bin/evn python

import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some 3-dim points
mean = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
cov = np.array([[1.0, -0.5, 0.8], [-0.5, 1.1, 0.0], [0.8, 0.0, 1.0]])
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 50)

# regular grid covering the domain of the data
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.5), np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.5))
XX = X.flatten()
YY = Y.flatten()

order = 1  # 1: linear, 2: quadratic
if order == 1:
    # best-fit linear plane
    A = np.c_[data[:, 0], data[:, 1], np.ones(data.shape[0])]
    C, _, _, _ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, data[:, 2])  # coefficients

    # evaluate it on grid
    Z = C[0] * X + C[1] * Y + C[2]

    # or expressed using matrix/vector product
    #Z = np.dot(np.c_[XX, YY, np.ones(XX.shape)], C).reshape(X.shape)

elif order == 2:
    # best-fit quadratic curve
    A = np.c_[np.ones(data.shape[0]), data[:, :2],
              np.prod(data[:, :2], axis=1), data[:, :2]**2]
    C, _, _, _ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, data[:, 2])

    # evaluate it on a grid
    Z = np.dot(np.c_[np.ones(XX.shape), XX, YY, XX * YY, XX**2, YY**2],
               C).reshape(X.shape)

# plot points and fitted surface
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.2)
ax.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], data[:, 2], c='r', s=50)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.axis('equal')
ax.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

**Actual outcome**

see this [link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10969)

**Expected outcome**

see this [link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10969)

The two styles are very different: the grid color, the wireframe, the surface color, etc. Is the style of this image from previous version of matplotlib? If so, how could I get that style?

**Matplotlib version**

- Operating system: Linux Mint 18.3
- Matplotlib version: 2.2.2
- Matplotlib backend: Qt4Agg
- Python version: 2.7.12

I installed matplotlib via pip in a virtual environment.

Comment: Back to the drawing board; visit the gallery, docs, examples..??

Comment: If possible, you should switch to Python 3.6+.  https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: Thanks @wwii I tried 3.6.5, but still can't get the desired style. Any ideas?

Comment: in Python 3.5, matplotlib 2.2.2 `plt.style.use('classic')` works

Comment: Thanks! @f5r5e5d It works! I didn't know 3d plots could also use styles. It seems some styles doesn't work? Also, could you make your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my Python 3.5, matplotlib 2.2.2 installation  plt.style.use('classic') seems to work

[Why matplotlib graphs and icons look different on two computers with the same OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49567227/why-matplotlib-graphs-and-icons-look-different-on-two-computers-with-the-same-os)  is similar but the Q was about icons